# Retrieving BLOB data from MySQL with Ruby and saving it as file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, blob

I just want to know how to retrieve BLOB data saved in a database(MySQL) by using Ruby and save the retrieve data as a file in a specific directory.

Let's say I have 'abc.wav' saved as BLOB in DB, and I want my Ruby code to get it from the database and save it in a folder named "sound_files".

Anyone here who knows how to do it?

Edit:
As of now, I am using the following code as shown below. 
The problem about it is that the outputted file is only "0 kb" in size which I guess indicates that it is not outputted properly.

```
wav_data = getWavFiles(db_ip, db_id, db_pass, db_schema)
wav_data.each do | wav |
    path = "path/to/file" + wav.filename
    File.open(path, 'w')
    File.write(path, wav.blobfile)
end
```

(Assuming that `wav.filename` is the filename, and `wav.blobfile` is the blob data which I both retrieved from the DB)
Any suggestions about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this in a Rake task or in the Rails console:

```
MyModel.find_each do |wav|
  filename = Rails.root.join('path/to/file', wav.filename)
  File.open(filename, 'wb') { |file| file.write(wav.blobfile) }
end
```

Change `MyModel` to your models name.

Comment: Thanks and I've tried your suggested code. The only problem is that the outputted file is "0kb" in size which is very odd and means it is not properly outputted. Any suggestions about this? :)

Comment: @Laurice : I updated my answer (note the `'wb'`). Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model is called Song you can do some thing like this.

```
Song.all.each do |song|
  blob = song.blob
  path = File.join("home","user","sound_files") #assuming you are on a nix* system
  File.write(path+song.name,blob)
end
```

Essentially we are getting a list of all songs and looping though each of them and getting the blob for each song and saving the desired location.

NOTE: if you have a lot of songs you might want to use [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each).

Comment: You should **not** use string operators to build file paths. That's what `File.join` is for.

Comment: yeah, you edited the wrong part. That one was fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action, e.g. `blob_to_file` and do something like this, let's assume `filename` is name of your BLOB file and `blob` is the column name

```
def blob_to_file
  record = Model.where(id: params[:id]).first

  File.open(record.filename, 'w') do |f|
    f.write record.blob
  end
end
```

Hope this help!